# How to correctly define an asynchronous function in a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, asynchronous, flutter-dependencies

I was working on a flutter project and for simplicity's sake, decided to allow the redirection of users for the "Help & Support" section towards the website. So, I tried to create an asynchronous function to allow that redirection.

So, I tried to use a Future function that uses the launchURL from called **launch_url**.

```
Future<void> _launchURL(Uri url) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
    await launchUrl(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

However, it always threw this exception:

```
I/UrlLauncher(30788): component name for https://flutter.dev/ is null
I/UrlLauncher(30788): component name for https://flutter.dev is null
E/flutter (30788): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch https://flutter.dev/
E/flutter (30788): #0      _launchURL (package:clothing_app/screens/settings.dart:385:5)
E/flutter (30788): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30788):
```

Note: When I tried to run on the computer of a friend of mine, it worked without that exception.

On both occasions, we used the **Android Studio** emulators to see the layouts of the app and **VS Code** to write our flutter code (connected to the emulator device). I additionally tried to run the code on my physical phone, but the same problem occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did not add the `<queries> …</queries>` meta data required by **url_launcher** on *AndroidManifest.xml*

Please refer to the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)